# Use IE webdriver Without using IDEServer

Tags: selenium, webdriver, build-automation, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I need to use IE webdriver Without using IDEServer .If i dont use "InternetExplorerDriver"
and path it gives this error.

IEDriverServer.exe does not exist-The file c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\TestProject1\TestProject1\bin\Debug\IEDriverServer.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list .

Is there an way to connect to IEDriver without running IDEServer and also need override security error"There is a problem with this website's security certificate."
Are there any alternatives

```
        IWebDriver driver;
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        //options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("D://Software", options); 

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");//EXAMPLE

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
        IWebElement uname = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_uxContentPlaceHolder_uxUsername"));
        uname.SendKeys("chris");
        IWebElement pwd = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_uxContentPlaceHolder_uxPassword"));
        pwd.SendKeys("chris1*");
```

Comment: I've supplied the answer to your question, but as a follow up, you said that you "need to use IE WebDriver Without using IDEServer". This begs the question of why you think you need to avoid using the standalone executable. What is the use case that "requires" you to not use IEDriverServer.exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually two different questions. To answer the one indicated in the summary line of this post, no, you now **must** have the IEDriverServer.exe in order to use WebDriver with IE in most of the official language bindings (.NET, Python, and Ruby). As of this writing, the Java language bindings provide a fallback mechanism using a .dll version of the IEDriverServer, but this is being phased out within the next couple of releases, and at that time the requirement for the IEDriverServer.exe will extend to Java as well.